# How to set landscape orientation for single view using sliding menu?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am implementing sliding menu using `SWRevealViewController` .My app is running in portait mode .But I wan to open a view Controller in Landscape mode.
This View controller is opening on Click on one view of sliding menu.
I've search on Stackoverflow, But all need `UINavigation` controller is to be set as an rootViewController in AppDelegate.
But in my case `SWrevealViewController` is set as an `rootviewController` of window.
Please help me by giving some clue.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem by using bellow code in the view which will be appear to be in landscape mode.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
        {
            objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft );
        }
    }
}


-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)){
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(setOrientation:)])
        {
            objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are calling a private API, aren't you?

Comment: No , I am SWRevealViewController library for creating sliding facebook like sliding menu,it is an open source

Comment: @MarcMosby Please tell me if I am doing some wrong.

Comment: I was talking about the `objc_msgSen` part

Comment: Could you explain something about objc_msgSec , Because  I have no idea about this ,I have just use it ,It working fine ,Apple have any restriction for their use , Please guide me. Thanks for reply

Comment: It seems to me like you are using a method (`setOrientation`) which you should not be able to use. The property `orientation` is `readonly` and therefore should not be used by developers. It may work, but your app may be rejected if you want to submit it to the app store.

Comment: Then ,please tell me how I change the orientation of device ,My App is for above iOS6 , Because I want to show one view in Landscape mode only .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49063/discussion-between-kdrocks-and-marc-mosby)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

by,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return  UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks , But I've set portait mode in Project Explorer >General setting. there is any change required here.

Comment: Yes, you need to set it as both if you want landscape orientation

Comment: Ok. But after writing Above method , it give error duplicate method  and after setting landscape mode in Project explorer setting .all view    will start rotating in lanscape or portait mode..but I didn't want to rotate any other view

Comment: KDRocks as @SamkitJain suggested you have to set both orientation in general settings and overwrite above given method to all you pages as you required. for both orientation use two otherwise return only Potrait.

Comment: If I set both orientation in general settings and overwrite above given method to all you pages as you required. for both orientation use two otherwise return only Potrait. Then all view is also have rotating capablity.I've try as you say above.